# Invalid Procedure Error when changing Pivot Table Source?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to set a formula that chooses a new source for an already existing pivot table.  For some reason, I get an invalid procedure error.  Any advice on what's wrong?

```
Set Data_Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryResults")
Set Pivot_Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
PivotName = "PivotTable1"
NewRange = Sheets("QueryResults").Range("$A$1:$AY$200")

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").PivotTables(PivotName). _
ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange)
```

Comment: This is something I would record a macro for while performing the task

Comment: Which line causes the error? (If no other way is available, try determining this by removing lines one by one.)